# Placing text over an image issue

Tags: jquery, css

I'm having the following issue,I would like to insert this text in the picture when the picture is faded.The problem is that the text position changes just once and it doesn't affect the other items from the selector.Can you please enlighten me what is going wrong?
I loop through all items and register the hover and mouseout event for them but the result isn't the one that I expect.

```
var informationText = $("#informationText");
        informationText.text("More info");
        informationText.hide();
        var element = $(".crop");
        element.children('img').each(function () {
            $(this).hover(function () {
                $(this).fadeTo(400, 0.1);
                var position = $(this).position();
                informationText.css({
                    position: "absolute",
                    top: position.top,
                    left : position.left
                });
                informationText.show();
            });
            $(this).mouseout(function () {
                $(this).fadeTo(400, 1);
                informationText.hide();
            });
        });

                 <---------- HTML section --------------->
            <a href="@member.url">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6" style="width: @memberWidth">
                    <div class="crop">
                        <img src="@imgUrl" class="img-responsive img-circle fancy" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h5 id="informationText"></h5>
            </a>
```

Comment: would be better if you give HTML code so we can help you

Comment: ok I'm with a fiddle right now, so since english it is not my native language, I'm not sure what is your problem. when i hover the img the text shows, and when it is not hover just shows the image.

Comment: I got 3 images that render not a single one.If its 1 image it would be alright.

Comment: sorry has been crazy days at work, 10pm and still at the work. I'll look into it asap. would be perfect if you could make your html w/ 3 imgs instead @imports